# Using mongodump to create a single file for each mongo database

Tags: mongodb, batch-file, mongodump

I am attempting to create a single archive file for each database in Mongo. Is there a way to create a batch file that will automatically create an archive (.archive) for each database without me manually entering the database name?

The snipet provided

```
mongodump --host hostename --port portname --username username --password password --authenticationDatabase admin --db databasename --archive=name.arvhive
```

I would like to create the archive file without having to specify the database name. Is this possible? If not, is there a way to dump all of the databases and create a single gzip for each database?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the DB names in the mongo instance we need to use the mongo `show dbs` command.

Since we want to be able to use this inside a script, we want to run that command and exit the mongo cli, to do that we can pass a `js` file to mongo, like so:

```
$ echo "show dbs" > showDbs.js
$ mongo < showDbs.js
```

Which will result in something like

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.22
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.22
admin   0.000GB
animals  0.366GB
people   0.012GB
local   0.000GB
bye
```

Since we need to parse the result, we can use the `--quiet` option to reduce the output. We can also skip creating the `showDbs.js` file so that we don't have to clean it up later.
Now we have:

```
$ mongo --quiet <<< "show dbs"
admin   0.000GB
animals  0.366GB
people   0.012GB
local   0.000GB
```

All that's left to do is to parse the result to remove the db sizes, and then run the `mongodump` command for each of the databases (I'm leaving that command as it is)

To remove the size information for each database we'll use `sed` and match for a whitespace, since whitespaces are not allowed in database names

```
$ sed 's/\s\+.\+//' <<< "$dbs"
```

Putting it all together we get the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
dbs=$(mongo --quiet <<< "show dbs")
dbs=$(sed 's/\s\+.\+//' <<< "$dbs")

for db in $dbs; do
mongodump --host hostname --port portname --username username --password password --authenticationDatabase admin --db $db --archive=$db.archive
done
```